# Navbar brand being stretched on bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

Using bulma there's an option to set a brand logo for the website. This brand, however, is being displayed differently across browsers. The image on discussion has the size of 640x160 and the fault is shown down below on Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome respectively. The logo image is stretched vertically on chrome making it look ugly.

[image: Mozilla Firefox]
[image: Google Chrome]

I inspected the DOM and I found that disabling a rule on `.navbar-brand` (`display: flex`) it corrects the brand size but it has other effects as in the mobile version the `.navbar-burguer` is located on another row (as it has a `block` display) and on Moz Firefox the links presented inside the `navbar-menu` disappear. What is causing this weird behavior over `navbar-brand`?

**Edit**

I use a static generator for the HTML pages, so you should see some liquid code for the navbar, and it is written as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar is-spaced has-text-weight-light" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <img class="navbar-item" src="/assets/img/logos/direc.png" width="164" height="41">

      <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" data-target="nav-menu">
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <ul id="nav-menu" class="navbar-menu">
      {% for link in site.navigation %}
      <li><a href="{{ link.url }}" class="navbar-item">{{ link.text }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}

      <div class="navbar-end">
        <li><a href="/login.html" class="button is-info">LOGIN</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: To the down voter, care to explain why?

Comment: I think, he downvoted, because a blurred image that should show the problem, is bad. Instead, remove the image and provide the relevant code.

Comment: The blurred images doesn't show up much information, they are only names for specific areas of the web page. The fact that the images show two different images does not affect anything in the resolution as well. Thanks for the heads up @Sun! I didn't provide any code and that is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image must be **surrounded** by a **hyperlink**.

```
<a class="navbar-item" href="#">
   <img class="navbar-item" src="..." width="164" height="41">
</a>
```

The **structure** of the **Bulma navbar** is:

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
      <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
    </a>

  <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">...</div>
    <div class="navbar-end">...</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

### In total

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css">

<nav class="navbar is-spaced has-text-weight-light" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
        <img class="navbar-item" src="http://via.placeholder.com/160/640" width="164" height="41">
      </a>

      <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" data-target="nav-menu">
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="nav-menu" class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-start">
        <ul>
          {% for link in site.navigation %}
          <li><a href="{{ link.url }}" class="navbar-item">{{ link.text }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-end">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="/login.html" class="button is-info">LOGIN</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Well, I removed this hyperlink because I didn't want to make a stylesheet specific for the navbar-brand appear not to be a link but that showed to be more of a problem than a solution. Thanks Sun.

Comment: You are welcome. Added some information. Yes, you could do `<div class="navbar-brand"><a class="my-logo navbar-item" href="#"><img ...></a>...</div>` and change style at `.my-logo`.

Comment: That's exactly what I just did, but instead of a class I used an `id`.

Comment: Ah, ok. One could add `!important` at the end of the declaration, if nothing has changed.