# In Bulma CSS, how to ensure the navbar brand logo is not stretched

Tags: bulma

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989908/navbar-brand-being-stretched-on-bulma) however the answer provided there does not work for me.

I am trying to ensure that my navbar's brand logo is not stretched. When I follow the instructions, and use just the relevant navbar code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar is-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="/"
          ><img
            class="navbar-item"
            src="/inc/speakUniqueLogo.png"
            alt="SpeakUnique"
            width="88"
            height="79"
        /></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <main class="pageContent">This is the page content.</main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the image is squashed:

[image]

Through trial & error I can make it display ok on desktop browsers, mainly by removing the width & height attributes, and removing `navbar-item` from the `<img>` tag's class, but that still stretches it on mobile (not on Chrome mobile emulator, but on iOS devices). When I follow the instructions more closely it's stretched on desktop as well.

What is the correct way in bulma to set a navbar brand logo which will keep it looking ok across devices?

Comment: You found a solution ? @Jeremy Jones

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989908/navbar-brand-being-stretched-on-bulma

Comment: No, not yet. @parrycima I know that other question has one answer but no luck using it.

Answer (score 4):

The solution can be this:

**CSS**

```
#header-logo{
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/160/640) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 152px
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar is-spaced has-text-weight-light" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a id="header-logo" class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">

      </a>

      <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" data-target="nav-menu">
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="nav-menu" class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-start">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">pagelinks</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```